# Como popular um Picker com dados do Banco (Firebase) - React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-database, reactive-programming

Eu estou tentando popular este Picker com dados do BD (para quando a pessoa quiser deletar, ela escolha por titulo), mas ele n preenche, e eu não sei se estou fazendo certo. agradeço a ajuda! :)

```
export default class delanuncio extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      titulo:[]
    };
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{
      if(user){
        firebase.database().ref('Tarefas').child(user.uid).once('value', (snapshot)=>{
          let state = this.state;
          state.titulo =[];

          snapshot.forEach((childItem)=>{
              state.titulo.push({
              key: childItem.key,
              titulo:childItem.val().titulo
            });
          });
          this.setState(state);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <Text style={styles.logoText}>Deletar Anuncio</Text>
        <Text>{'\n'}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.texto}>Titulo do Anuncio:</Text>
        <Picker
          selectedValue={this.state.titulo}
          style={styles.picker}
          onValueChange={({itemValue}, itemIndex) => <Picker.Item key={titulo} label={titulo} value={titulo} />
          }>          

        </Picker>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Deletar Anuncio</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que eu vi do seu código, os elementos do picker estão de um array chamado "titulo" dentro do seu state.

Eu recomendo você criar no state um campo chamado "titulo_selecionado" para guardar o valor escolhido no picker.

```
this.state = {
titulo:[],
 titulo_selecionado: ""
 };
```

Para exibir este conteúdo do array "titulo" no picker,  você teria que fazer o seguinte:

```
<Picker
selectedValue={this.state.titulo_selecionado}
style={styles.picker}
 onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
this.setState({ titulo_selecionado: itemValue})
}
>
{this.state.titulo.map((item, index) => {
return (
<Picker.Item
label={item.titulo}
value={item.titulo}
key={index}
 />
 );
})}
</Picker>
```

No código acima, eu alterei o "onValueChange" para atualizar o state com o valor do item selecionado.

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo! ;)